# Can repulsively interacting particles form a solid?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, gas

Consider the system of itinerant classical interacting particles
$$
H = \sum_i \frac{p_i^2}{2m} + \sum_{ij} \frac{J}{r_{ij}^\alpha}
$$
in $d$-dimensions, where we assume the interactions are repulsive $J >0$.

At fixed density $\rho$ and temperature $T$, my naive intuition is to think of the problem as one of hard-spheres of a radius $R = (J/k T)^{1/\alpha}$ set by the excluded volume. Hence one might expect the system be solid (i.e. there is long range order in the molecule positions) for $\rho R^d \gtrsim 1$, the scale at which it becomes necessary for the spheres to form a dense packing.

Is this intuition valid, or does it only apply for a potential with a finite range, and instead I have missed some subtlety due to the long-range inter-particle potential?

Comment: can you give an example of what you mean by repulsive? If the system is all same charge for example, it will be repulsive but that it cannot form a solid is self evident

Comment: @annav Things are [expected to be much more subtle than you think](http://www.sklogwiki.org/SklogWiki/index.php/Hard_disk_model). I don't know what's the current status on this topic, so I won't provide an answer. At least in 2d, it is rigorously known that you cannot have a strict solid phase (but you may have a spontaneous breaking of rotation invariance).

Comment: @annav It seems self-evident that hard disks do solidify. If you stack a bunch of balls in a box with a dense packing, and shake it, they won't move. My question here can be understood as asking what class of potentials exhibit similar phenomena.

Comment: @YvanVelenik Is your 2D comment just a Mermin Wagner type statement, or is there more to it? I am also confused as it contradicts your link, which claims there is a solid phase for hard spheres in 2D.

Comment: @annav Another related example is Wigner crystals and their generalizations, which have been observed in various systems. Though here we are considering classical, and not quantum mechanical particles.

Comment: Yes, it is a Mermin-Wagner type theorem. It excludes spontaneous breaking of translation invariance in two-dimensional systems. See [this paper by Richthammer](https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.3637) (he also has some more recent, more quantitative results). Regtarding *"it contradicts your link"*: in the link I provided in my previous comment, the claim is that there is a quasi-long range order (a kind of "soft" solid).

Comment: @YvanVelenik Yeah the QLRO makes sense. Thanks for the Richthammer paper.

Comment: If you have a crystal, then in the nodes of the crystal the force is zero but any perturbation from that position can generate an infinite force if $\alpha$ is not big enough (e.g. if the force is independent of the distance).

Comment: @JGBM I agree. Otherwise stated, the total energy is extensive only for $\alpha > d$.