# Will spinless particles with repulsive interaction solidify at high enough pressure?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, phase-transition

I'm trying to understand better the formation of solids, such as when high pressure can induce a material to turn into a solid. In the following, I want to consider a toy model of $N$ spinless particles described by the Hamiltonian

$$ H = \sum_{i} {\frac{\vec{p}_i^2}{2m}} + a\sum_{j}\sum_{i<j} \delta(\vec{x}_i - \vec{x}_j) $$

The boundary conditions are periodic; the system is in a periodic box of side length $L$ and volume $V=L^d$.

As I increase $\frac{N}{V}$, will I eventually reach a regime where the ground state is in a "solid" phase?

As a caveat, I'm not entirely sure how I should define the system as being in a solid phase. Perhaps that the pair correlation function in the ground state shows well-defined peaks and does not smoothly asymptote to a constant value?

---

Please note that I will accept answers that are discussing the $T=0$ ground state properties, though a comment on the behavior at small, nonzero $T$ might also be appreciated. For example, I'm tempted that nonzero $T$ should destroy any crystalline order in $d=1,2$ by Mermin-Wagner.

Comment: Surely your Hamiltonian will end up describing a gas of particles, right? I would expect a true solid to reach its ($T=0$) ground state when the particles were arranged in some lattice. But your Hamiltonian has only contact interactions, so there's no difference in energy between a lattice and a random distribution of particles with no contact. I think you may be looking for something like the [Debye model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debye_model).

Comment: @Andrew For me, the Debye model is putting the lattice in by hand, while I'm more interested in whether a lattice can emerge. For example, if one considers Coulomb-interacting electrons with a background positive charge (the jellium model), there is spontaneous breaking of the continuous translational symmetry at low enough density of electrons to form a lattice of electrons (the Wigner crystal).

Comment: @Andrew If I had instead done a hard-core interaction where particles had a radius but could not overlap, I think it would be somewhat likely that at high densities the particles would be forced into a close packing arrangement. I chose my delta-function repulsive potential as a weakening of such a hard-core interaction, and so it's less clear that it indeed has a solid structure at a high density.

Comment: a similar question with no answers is https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/775776/can-repulsively-interacting-particles-form-a-solid

Comment: @annav Thanks for pointing that question out. I agree that it's quite similar. However, there's the possibility that the delta function potential may ultimately give different behavior than power-law interactions since it's strictly zero range. Please let me know if you think my question is a duplicate of that one.

Comment: As far as I can guess, it is not a duplicate, it all depends on the mathematical model to be used, which has to be different due to different assumptions